# The slope of a sum of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Assuming I have a set of linear equations:

$$ y_1 = a_1x_1 + b_1 $$
$$ y_2 = a_2x_2 + b_2 $$

Is it correct that the sum of these are:

$$ z1 = y1 + y2 $$

This then means that the y-intersect and slope is:

$$ \text{y-intersect} = b_1+b_2 $$

$$ slope =  a_1 + a_ 2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is the correct y intersect and slope for the z1 equation.